# Difference between database backup and data-tier application export

Tags: sql-server

I don't know if this is a bad question, but I don't understand what the difference is between normal DB backups and data-tier applications in SQL Server. I know backups can't be imported from SQL Server to an older version of SQL Server, but data-tier applications **do** work for this, and I've been using this to move some of our databases between servers. What are the differences from a backup perspective?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A backup is a full copy of all the database pages, or a dump of the database if you like, starting at page 0 and written sequentially to the backup device.

The Data-Tier application is a set of scripts that will create the database objects along with insert statements that will insert the data into the table objects afterwards.

From a backup perspective the Data-Tier application is a snapshot of the database in a certain state, you can install the application in that state but you can not restore additional data but have to copy the data from another source. The backup is a consistent state of the database and you can make log or differential backups that you can use to restore the database to a point in time.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: There's one important caveat: _"For an export to be transactionally consistent, you must ensure either that no write activity is occurring during the export, or that you are exporting from a transactionally consistent copy of your Azure SQL database."_ ([azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export)). 

This means that if you export Data-Tier application from a a live db, you can get an inconsistent set of data (at least for Azure Sql, not sure about regular Sql Server).

Comment: Can this be explained by saying that back-ups are like a book of data-tiers (snapshots)? I'm not still sure to understand what a back-up really is.